# Table name is different when using Heidisql instead of Sql Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, heidisql

Previously I was using the SQL Server 2008 Management Studio for my ASP.Net project. Database was on localhost. Now I moved the database to server and tried to connect it with SQL Server Management Studio but it was not working well with server. When I was adding table it said something like indexes are full. When I searched I got to know that it may be the version conflict as server SQL Server version may be different.

So I decided to use HeidiSql to connect to database. All goes well, but when I added a new table, HeidiSql created it like `'NewUser.tablename'`. `NewUser` is the username for database. All the previous tables are like `'dbo.tablename'`.

Why HeidiSql is saving like this? I tried every setting in HeidiSql but nothing is happening.

Comment: When you login by a login-user there is a `User Mapping` for each database that sets the `User` and `Default Schema` of that database and that `Default Schema` will apply as Table_Schema like `dbo`, So this is dependent to your login user and its `User Mapping` ;).

Comment: @shA.t will it effect my software to having multiple Schema tables?

Comment: Having multiple schema tables will effect on accessing to tables and writing queries and using other database objects ;).

Comment: @shA.t So how can I handle this schema thing? Now I have two schemas in my database.